# Can i do a findby for mutliple parameters in cosmos db spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, azure-cosmosdb

I have a DB with a single partition key, say `prop1`. So i know i can do a `findByProp1` and also a `findAll` . Can i do a `findByProp1andProp2andProp3` etc where `prop2 ,prop3` are not specified as partition keys but can be found in every item in a collection  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can make use of the aforementioned method of searching for tuples in db on the basis of multiple properties. Spring data specification defines that you can search with multiple keys given they exist in the Model of the table you are searching in.
methods are defined in the DAO as

`List<Model> findByProp1AndProp2(String prop1, String prop2)`

Assuming both prop1 and prop2 are of String type, although they can be of any compatible datatype as defined in the Model.